# using \ac cmmand produces wrong pluralization

Tags: acronyms

I call this command:

```
\acro{BVH}{Bounding Volume Hierarchy}
\acp{BVH}
```

I am getting this result:

[image]

How do I tell it to use the correct form of the plural?

Comment: yes, thank you for the answer